# Search through laravel relations with builder

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to work on a query builder in Laravel and want to search through a model's relations. So far my code looks like this:

```
$search = (new City)->newQuery();

// Search for a city based on its state.
if ($request->has('state')) {
    $inquiry->whereHas('state', function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->whereState($request->state);
    });
}
```

So I have a `City` model and a `State` model. The query is supposed to look through cities and then check each one's state relation and extract the model with the relevant states.

The code doesn't produce any errors, just an empty object.

Comment: Are you executing the query with `->get()`?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
City::when(request()->has('state'), function($query){
    $query->whereHas('state', function ($query){
        $query->where('state', request()->input('state'));
    });
})->get()
```